# Fabricjs mouse:down event fires twice

Tags: javascript, ajax, fabricjs

The script gets the JSON data via AJAX request and then renders on the Canvas. The thing is that there are multiple buttons on the same page with canvas and each button triggers a new AJAX request and renders the returned JSON data.

Problem occurs every other second render (this is strange). For example on the 1st render mouse:down event works, on 2nd render it fires twice, on 3rd render it works, on 4th render it fires twice and so on..

Here is the script that triggered on every button click:

```
// objects variable is the JSON returned from AJAX request and
// all of it fabricJS objects.
var drawing = JSON.parse(objects);

for (var i = 0; i < drawing.objects.length; i++) {
    drawing.objects[i]['left'] += 50;
}

canvas.clear();
canvas.loadFromJSON(drawing, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

canvas.setZoom(0.66);
canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() * 1.3);

canvas.on('mouse:down', function (el) {
    console.log(el.target);
}
```

**EDIT** Apperantly I was using the same event listener on every render. That's why it fires twice on the second render, three times on the third render and so on..

Comment: Are you binding the same listener multiple times for `mouse:down`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `canvas.off('mouse:down')` before adding another `mouse:down` event to canvas. If you want only one event. `canvas.off` will remove the event attached to canvas.

**DEMO**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
function addEvent(){
 canvas.on('mouse:down',function(){
  console.log('mouseDown');
 })
}
function removeEvent(){
 canvas.off('mouse:down');
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick='addEvent()'>addEvent</button>
<button onclick='removeEvent()'>removeEvent</button>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```